# Importance of apps orders in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

Is the order of apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` important? I ask it because I have `settings` folder with two `settings` files: `base.py` and `production.py` and I put all my settings in `base.py` and then in `production.py`, I have:

```
from base import *
```

and then I override some settings. 
Also in my `base.py`, I make `INSTALLED_APPS` a list, not a tuple. Because I want to remove some apps for `production` settings. 
In `production.py` I want to write:

```
NOT_USED_APPS = ['debut_toolbar', 'other_odd_app',]
INSTALLED_APPS = list(set(INSTALLED_APPS) - set(NOT_USED_APPS))
```

In this case, the order of apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` is not like in `base.py`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Yes, the order is quite important.**

From Django official docs on [`INSTALLED_APPS` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

> When several applications provide different versions of the same
>   resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the
>   application listed first in `INSTALLED_APPS` has precedence.

**Example-1 Templates:**

**[`django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader)**

If this template loader is enabled in your `DjangoTemplates` backend in the `TEMPLATES` setting or if you have passed it as a loaders argument to Engine, then it loads templates from Django apps on the filesystem.

For each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django will look for templates in there.

Lets say in my project, i have defined `INSTALLED_APPS` as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('myproject.app1', 'myproject.app2')
```

Now, i want to get the template `some_template.html`. Then `get_template('some_template.html')` will look for `some_template.html` in these directories, **in this order:**

```
/path/to/myproject/app1/templates/ # checks here first
/path/to/myproject/app2/templates/ # Then checks here
```

**It will then use the one which it finds first.**

Quoting from that [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader):

> The order of `INSTALLED_APPS` is significant!

**Example-2: Translations**

Django applies the following algorithm for discovering translations:

1. The directories listed in `LOCALE_PATHS` have the highest precedence, with the ones appearing first having higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
2. Then, it looks for and uses if it exists a `locale` directory in each of the installed apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. **The ones appearing first have higher precedence than the ones appearing later.**
3. Finally, the Django-provided base translation in `django/conf/locale` is used as a fallback.

We can see that order is important here also.

**Example-3 Management Commands:**

From Django 1.7 release notes on [management commands and order of `INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#management-commands-and-order-of-installed-apps):

> When several applications provide management commands with the same
>   name, Django loads the command from the application that comes first
>   in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Previous versions loaded the command from the
>   application that came last.
>
> This brings discovery of management commands in line with other parts
>   of Django that rely on the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`, such as static
>   files, templates, and translations.

Comment: This seems to match every other explanation for app-ordering that I've seen, but it doesn't match my experience. Django's core apps and other reusable apps define default templates that you can override, yet most devs follow the convention of setting `INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS`. Based on the description in example 1, these overrides wouldn't actually take effect for these apps, since the local apps are (typically) listed last, but that isn't the case in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented a bit and found two other things that I deemed useful to know:

1. The order in `INSTALLED_APPS` doesn't seem to effect when the models are created. Django figures out that certain models depend on others and run them in the correct order.
2. The apps `ready` method in the `AppConfig` object seems to run in the order they appear in `INSTALLED_APPS`.