# Request object has no attribute 'oauth2_error' in DRF + DOT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

I'm using djangorestframework and django-oauth-toolkit for my API.

I have a fairly simple user logout view, which supports both DOT logout with token revoking and regular Django session logout:

```
class UserLogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        logout(request)

        if request.auth is None:
            return Response('OK')

        app = request.auth.application
        client_id = app.client_id
        client_secret = app.client_secret
        token = request.auth.token

        r = requests.post(settings.OAUTH_URL.format('revoke-token'), data={
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'token': token,
        })

        if r.status_code != 200:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Failed to revoke token')

        return Response('OK')
```

If something is wrong with token revoking I expect to get a 401 response with error, but instead I get an error on my server side (which is the result of raising `AuthenticationFailed` as states the traceback):

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'oauth2_error'
```

I suppose something is wrong with exception handling of DRF + DOT combination, but how to fix it?

**UPD:** Everything in my `settings.py` related to DRF, authentication or DOT:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**UPD 2:** I tried removing `SessionAuthentication` from `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` and setting my app order according to module documentation (writing `rest_framework` after `oauth2_provider`), everything with no luck.

Comment: Hmm it is odd indeed. Only thing i can come up with is that maybe the import/include of the packages order is not correct. Could you maybe check (just in case) if your settings.py do match the requirements in https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Comment: @Scircia, see my updated answer, I've added my settings.

Comment: Based on your settings.py it looks like the order of your installed apps (compared to the documentation) isn't corrrect. Make sure to include rest_framework after oauth2_provider. More information about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925587/6809132 Also inside the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES you're using two Authentication's. What's the reason you're using the rest_framework SessionAuthentication for? Try commenting that part out to see if this maybe causes the issue also. Hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: @Scircia, I'm using session authentication for legacy compatibility with an old app. As for app order -- I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: @Scircia, just tried changing the order, didn't work. I've also tried removing SessionAuthentication, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution: There is a bug in django-oauth-tookit 1.2.0 (see https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/pull/716) which has already been fixed in the master branch. Unfortunately, there is no new release, so I had to subclass OAuth2Authentication and provide the missing attribute:

```
 def authenticate_header(self, request):
     request.oauth2_error = {}
     return super().authenticate_header(request)
```